# How to open tweet in terminal through Android

Tags: android, twitter, terminal

I have created Android Twitter application where all the tweets are opened in my emulator. How can I open all these tweets onto the PC's Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information please? What do you mean with the PC's terminal?
If you mean the Android debug bridge (ADB), then you could use abd port forward to tunnal a tcp connection to your device.

Comment: No this is Hyper terminal like serial port,which is inbuilt in windowXP.and when I connect device with USB it will show the serial port number that where the device is connected..